# Trying to add an image from a JavaScript Array to the DOM on hover

Tags: javascript, html

Ok, this might be a bit of a complex ask. Essentially I am trying to make a sort of JavaScript character select screen. I have my UI all set up, and my images are all coded in HTML into the DOM.

What I have done is put each characters respective sprite image into a JavaScript object.

What I would like to do is have the characters sprite image appear to the side of the character select screen when the user HOVERS over the characters select image (inside of a container I have called "sprite-container").

I have the HTML like this...

```
        <div class="container character-container">
        <div class="row">
            <img src="assets/images/characters/sfa2_ryu.gif" alt="Ryu" class="character" id="Ryu" onclick="showRyu()">
            <img src="assets/images/characters/sfa2_adon.gif" alt="Adon" class="character" id="Adon">
            <img src="assets/images/characters/sfa2_chunli.gif" alt="Chun" class="character" id="Chun">
            <img src="assets/images/characters/sfa2_guy.gif" alt="Guy" class="character" id="Guy">
            <img src="assets/images/characters/sfa2_ken.gif" alt="Ken" class="character" id="Ken">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <img src="assets/images/characters/sfa2_dhalsim.gif" alt="Dhalsim" class="character">
            <img src="assets/images/characters/sfa2_gen.gif" alt="Gen" class="character">
            <img src="assets/images/characters/sfa2_sakura.gif" alt="Sakura" class="character">
            <img src="assets/images/characters/sfa2_rolento.gif" alt="Rolento" class="character">
            <img src="assets/images/characters/sfa2_zangief.gif" alt="Zangief" class="character">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <img src="assets/images/characters/sfa2_charlie.gif" alt="Charlie" class="character">
            <img src="assets/images/characters/sfa2_birdie.gif" alt="Birdie" class="character">
            <img src="assets/images/characters/sfa2_rose.gif" alt="Rose" class="character">
            <img src="assets/images/characters/sfa2_sodom.gif" alt="Sodom" class="character">
            <img src="assets/images/characters/sfa2_sagat.gif" alt="Sagat" class="character">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <img src="assets/images/characters/sfa2_akuma.gif" alt="Akuma" class="character">
            <img src="assets/images/characters/sfa2_bison.gif" alt="Bison" class="character">
            <img src="assets/images/characters/sfa2_dan.gif" alt="Dan" class="character">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
        <div class="sprite-container" id="sprite-container">
            <img src="" alt="" width="15%">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src='app.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my javascript array...

```
//Character Sprites
const Sprites = [
    {
        id: 0,
        name: "Ryu",
        img: 'assets/images/sprites/RyuSprite.gif'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Adon",
        img: 'assets/images/sprites/AdonSprite.gif'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "ChunLi",
        img: 'assets/images/sprites/ChunliSprite.gif'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: "Guy",
        img: 'assets/images/sprites/GuySprite.gif'
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: "Ken",
        img: 'assets/images/sprites/KenSprite.gif'
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        name: "Dhalsim",
        img: 'assets/images/sprites/DhalsimSprite.gif'
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        name: "Gen",
        img: 'assets/images/sprites/GenSprite.gif'
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        name: "Sakura",
        img: 'assets/images/sprites/SakuraSprite.gif'
    },
    {
        id: 9,
        name: "Rolento",
        img: 'assets/images/sprites/RolentoSprite.gif'
    },
    {
        id: 10,
        name: "Zangief",
        img: 'assets/images/sprites/ZangiefSprite.gif'
    },
    {
        id: 12,
        name: "Charlie",
        img: 'assets/images/sprites/CharlieSprite.gif'
    },
    {
        id: 13,
        name: "Birdie",
        img: 'assets/images/sprites/BirdieSprite.gif'
    },
    {
        id: 14,
        name: "Rose",
        img: 'assets/images/sprites/RoseSprite.gif'
    },
    {
        id: 15,
        name: "Sodom",
        img: 'assets/images/sprites/SodomSprite.gif'
    },
    {
        id: 16,
        name: "Sagat",
        img: 'assets/images/sprites/SagatSprite.gif'
    },
    {
        id: 17,
        name: "Akuma",
        img: 'assets/images/sprites/AkumaSprite.gif'
    },
    {
        id: 18,
        name: "Bison",
        img: 'assets/images/sprites/BisonSprite.gif'
    },
    {
        id: 19,
        name: "Dan",
        img: 'assets/images/sprites/DanSprite.gif'
    },
]
```

Not sure if this is even possible... any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news: it's possible.

Generally speaking this is just a matter of adding a **mouseover** and **mouseout** event listener to your character selection screen, figure out which element you're currently hovering and updating the preview accordingly. We want to do this in an efficient way though.

Looking at your DOM structure you've grouped anything that belongs to the character selection inside a `<div>` with the class **container character-container**.
We can get a reference to this container using:

```
var container = document.getElementsByClassName("container character-container")[0];
```

The getElementsByClassName function returns a HTMLCollection which essentially is an array. Since there is only one object of that class we can directly access the object by appending `[0]`.

Now we can attach a mouseover event listener using:

```
container.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {

});
```

This event will fire as soon as the user moves the mouse over anything which is inside the container.

Unfortunately we are just interested in the `<img>` elements. To find out if we're hovering an image elment, we can query `e.target.tagName` - which in case we do returns the string **IMG**.

Now we can use your images **id** - e.g.  `id="Ryu"` - property to find the matching sprite image from the **Sprites** object using:

```
var obj = Sprites.find(o => o.name == e.target.id);
```

If we give the **sprite-container** `<div>` an unique id like **preview** we can change it's .src property to the one we read from the object.

```
document.getElementById("preview").src = obj.img;
```

Here's a striped down example based on your code:

```js
const Sprites = [{
    id: 0,
    name: "Ryu",
    img: 'https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Adon",
    img: 'https://picsum.photos/id/2/200/300'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Chun",
    img: 'https://picsum.photos/id/3/200/300'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Guy",
    img: 'https://picsum.photos/id/4/200/300'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Ken",
    img: 'https://picsum.photos/id/5/200/300'
  }
];

var container = document.getElementsByClassName("container character-container")[0];
container.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName == "IMG") {
    var obj = Sprites.find(o => o.name == e.target.id);
    document.getElementById("preview").src = obj.img;
  }
});
container.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
  document.getElementById("preview").src = null;
});
```

```html
<div class="container character-container">
  <div class="row">
    <img src="assets/images/characters/sfa2_ryu.gif" alt="Ryu" class="character" id="Ryu" onclick="showRyu()">
    <img src="assets/images/characters/sfa2_adon.gif" alt="Adon" class="character" id="Adon">
    <img src="assets/images/characters/sfa2_chunli.gif" alt="Chun" class="character" id="Chun">
    <img src="assets/images/characters/sfa2_guy.gif" alt="Guy" class="character" id="Guy">
    <img src="assets/images/characters/sfa2_ken.gif" alt="Ken" class="character" id="Ken">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="sprite-container" id="sprite-container">
      <img id="preview" src="" alt="" width="15%">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to get you started, you can use the `onmouseover` event listener.
For example, you can create a function that sets the container:

```
// add an Id to the image under the sprite container
var image = document.getElementById("sprite-item");
function changeContainer(url){
    image.src = url;
}
```

Then in HTML, you can add the attribute:

```
<img src="assets/images/characters/sfa2_ryu.gif" alt="Ryu" class="character" id="Ryu" onmouseover="changeContainer("assets/images/sprites/RyuSprite.gif")">
```